# don't read value of element in XML by xstream

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

i have an XML like below and i use XStream to parse this XML

```
<Annotation name="uniqueMembers">true</Annotation>
```

and a class for Annotation :

```
@XStreamAlias("Annotation")
public class Annotation {
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String name;

private String value;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

i need value have "true" of this tag but when i call

```
 xStream.fromXML("myXml.xml");
```

it have null value
why? how can i get "true" of this tag?

EDIT : 
part of MyXml.xml

```
<Dimension name="Branch" >
    <Hierarchy name="xxx" primaryKey="" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All" >
        <Table schema="vvv" name="ccc" />

        <Level name="State"  captionColumn="STATE_NAME" uniqueMembers="true" type="Integer" />
        <Level name="City"  captionColumn="CITY_NAME" uniqueMembers="true" type="Integer">
            <Annotations>
                <Annotation name="uniqueMembers">true</Annotation>
            </Annotations>
        </Level>
        <Level name="Branch" captionColumn="BRANCH_NAME" uniqueMembers="true" type="Integer" >
            <Annotations>
                <Annotation name="uniqueMembers">true</Annotation>
            </Annotations>
        </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

Comment: Can u paste here your myXml.xml?

Comment: its big and have alot of object but allright i'll do

Comment: i found an answer that works for me too

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672541/reading-xml-value-to-populate-java-variable>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written at the moment, the class you've shown there expects something like

```
<Annotation name="something">
  <value>the value</value>
</Annotation>
```

To get rid of the `<value>` element and just use the `<Annotation>` element's content, you need to use a `ToAttributedValueConverter`, [this blog post](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/using-xstream-to-map-single-element.html) has the details but essentially you need to add

```
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"value"})
```

as a class-level annotation on your `Annotation` class.

Comment: yeah you're right but it doesn't need <value> tag ... it work without it

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML snippet:

```
<Annotation>
    < uniqueMembers>true< /uniqueMembers>
</Annotation>
```

Comment: it isn't possible to change the tags